# Referring to sibling of parent div in HTML

Tags: html, parent, siblings

I have two `div` elements:

```html
<div id="one">
    <a href="#two">Link to two</a>
</div>
<div id="two">
    Link to me
</div>
```

This causes the following when I click on the link with `href` attribute being `#two`:

```html
http://domain.com/one#two
```

but I want:

```html
http://domain.com/#two
```

Is this possible without using javascript?

Comment: Why is your id '#two' instead of 'two'?

Comment: It's not, that was a typo. But either way, why is that grounds for a down vote? It is a concise question, detailed with what I have tried, and it has a clear right answer.

Comment: Is the name of your page 'one' by any chance?

Comment: The html file is multiplePerPageTest.html

Comment: So you are getting `/multiplePerPageTest.html#two` but you want `/#two`?

Comment: No, I'm getting /one#two and I want /#two

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or point us to an example page? That doesn't make any sense based on what you've shown. I don't see how '/one' should be part of the url unless it already was the url.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I'm with you, there's a strange behavior with his page.

Comment: I think the reason that is happening is the page is being loaded from another "index.html" and it is doing something funky with the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**Considering the strange behavior of your page, NO, it's not possible without JavaScript**.

On `click` event of the links, go to the location specified in the `href`:

### Javascript

```js
window.onload = function(){
    /* On window load event, we loop through each link */
    var a  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var elem in a)
    {
        /* If it's a DOMElement */
        if(a[elem].nodeType ==1)
        {
            /* We bind the window.location.href event, sending it to the value of the href attribute of the selected anchor element. */

            a[elem].addEventListener("click",function(e){window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');alert(window.location.href);});

            /* console.log(window.location.href); */
        }
    }
}
```

### [-->Live Demo<--](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/E9Xb8/)